# Wide-character version of _memccpy

Tags: c, string, visual-c++, concatenation, widechar

I have to concatenate wide C-style strings, and based on my research, it seems that something like [`_memccpy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memccpy?view=vs-2019) is [most ideal](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/08/12/efficient-string-copying-and-concatenation-in-c/) (in order to avoid [Shlemiel's problem](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)). But I can't seem to find a wide-character version.  Does something like that exist?

Comment: It would improve the question to show sample code where you set up and work with the strings in question

Comment: For reference, `wcscpy()` available since C95 and [VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-wcscpy-mbscpy?view=vs-2019).  What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: @chux It appears that `wcscpy` doesn't return a pointer to the end of the copied string, which is the main optimization offered by `_memccpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does something like that exist?

The C standard library does not contain a wide-character version of Microsoft's `_memccpy()`.  Neither does it contain `_memccpy()` itself, although *POSIX* specifies the `memccpy()` function on which MS's `_memccpy()` appears to be modeled.

POSIX also defines `wcpcpy()` (a wide version of `stpcpy()`), which copies a a wide string and returns a pointer to the end of the result.  That's not as fully featured as `memccpy()`, but it would suffice to avoid Shlemiel's problem, if only Microsoft's C library provided a version of it.

You can, however, use [`swprintf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-sprintf-l-swprintf-swprintf-l-swprintf-l?view=vs-2019) to concatenate wide strings without suffering from Shlemiel's problem, with the added advantage that it *is* in the standard library, since C99.  It does not provide the `memccpy` behavior of halting after copying a user-specified (wide) character, but it does return the number of wide characters written, which is equivalent to returning a pointer to the end of the result.  Also, it can directly concatenate an arbitrary fixed number of strings in a single call.  `swprintf` does have significant overhead, though.

But of course, if the overhead of `swprintf` puts you off then it's pretty easy to write your own.  The result might not be as efficient as a well-tuned implementation from your library vendor, but we're talking about a scaling problem, so you mainly need to win on the asymptotic complexity front.  Simple example:

```
/*
 * Copies at most 'count' wide characters from 'src' to 'dest', stopping after
 * copying a wide character with value 0 if that happens first. If no 0 is
 * encountered in the first 'count' wide characters of 'src' then the result
 * will be unterminated.
 * Returns 'dest' + n, where n is the number of non-zero wide characters copied to 'dest'.
 */
wchar_t *wcpncpy(wchar_t *dest, const wchar_t *src, size_t count) {
    for (wchar_t *bound = dest + count; dest < bound; ) {
        if ((*dest++ = *src++) == 0) return dest - 1;
    }
    return dest;
}
```